# Не работает редактирование в админке wordpress

Tags: cms, wordpress

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Не могу понять, почему в админке wordpress не работает изменение страниц и записей, открываю список страниц, нажимаю кнопку "изменить" для редактирования - и мне пишет ошибку, что страница не найдена...

Comment: Проблема возникла после переноса домена?

Comment: Да, после переноса.

Comment: Ошибка выводится в дизайне WP или как системная ошибка сервера?
Киньте URL, который открывается после того, как Вы нажали изменить.

На всякий случай кидаю ссылку на скрипт, которым пользуюсь, когда переношу сайт WP на новый домен:
http://z-site.ru/notes/perenos-sajta-wordpress-na-novyj-domen-n228.html

Посмотрите, может быть, в какие-то таблицы Вы не внесли изменения.
____
Если данные из базы выгружаются, но не поддаются изменениям может быть проблема в правах пользователя БД, т.е. запрещено редактирование БД.

Comment: В `wp_options` попадаются сериализованные php массивы и объекты, если тупо сделать с ними find-and-replace (при условии изменения длинны домена), то  массивы станут просто коцаными. Ядро WP более-менее переживает столько грубое обращение со своими данными, а вот как поведут себя сторонние плагины (которые тоже любят сорить в БД, в частности в `wp_options`, в частности сериализованными массивами), заранее знать нельзя.

Давеча писал скрипт для миграции WP, так пришлось написать подскрипт на php для рекурсивной обработки массивов (с произвольной вложенностью). А потому случайно удалил его ):

Comment: Да, ошибка выводится в дизайне WP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Блог переносился с домена в домен/поддомен или в подпапку?

Если да, то могут быть попутаны параметры Адрес WordPress и Адрес сайта в разделе Настройки - Общие.

Comment: Да, сайт переносился на домен, но в настройках стоит полный адрес того домена, на который переносили.
________

И не могу добавлять записи.

Comment: @kiberchainik, адрес сайта по всей БД прописан. Ищите статьи по миграции, там всю `wp_posts` надо корячить и еще пару опций.

Comment: Я всю базу перекорячил уже, проблема осталась.